# Generics question

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have:

```
public interface Action<S extends Shape> {
  public void start( S shape );
}
```

Why do I get the following?

```
public <S extends Shape> void performAction( Action<S> action, Shape shape ) {
  action.start(shape);  // error: cannot supply Shape
}
```

In other words, in the future, I might have subclasses of `Shape` and `Action`s that operate on them like:

```
Action<Rectangle>
Action<Blob>
```

I'd like to have a uniform interface that can apply `Action`s to a bunch of different subclasses of `Shape`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need something like this:

```
public <S extends Shape> void performAction(Action<S> action, S shape) {
     action.start(shape);
}
```

However in this case it not clear what value there is in using generics if all you are interested in is `Shape` and its subclasses. The code below would accomplish the same thing.

```
public interface Action {
    public void start(Shape someShape);
}

public void performAction(Action action, Shape someShape) {
    action.start(someShape); 
}
```

If however the `Action` class is completely generic and can be used with objects other than `Shape` and its subclasses then you could do the following:

```
public interface Action<S> {
    public void start(S target);
}

public <S> void performAction(Action<S> action, S target) {
    action.start(target);
}
```

Comment: +1. In the original code, there was no guarantee that `shape` was of whatever type `action` was expecting.

Comment: In this case, I think generics just over complicates things.

Comment: @jjnguy, Agreed generics do seem unnecessary in this simple case.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you necessarily need generics in this case.  Here is what I would do:

```
public interface Action {
  public void start( Shape someShape );
}

public void performAction( Action action, Shape someShape ) {
  action.start(someShape); 
}
```

Then you can pass any type that extends `Shape` into the method `start()`.

Comment: But suppose the Action needs to make use of some method in a subclass of Shape, i.e. like getWidth() method for a Rectangle.  In this case, running an Action meant for a rectangle on a Shape object will require casting, and is no longer generally safe.  What to do?

Comment: If that were the case, give Shape a method called `getWidth()` and properly override it in all the subclasses.

Comment: @Jake See directly above comment.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `start` requires an `S`, but you are passing it a `Shape`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the action is for a specialization of shape, not any shape.

Answer (score 1):

For a basic need, I suggest:

```
public interface Action {
  public void start(Shape shape );
}
```

Or if you need to type them stronger, you could change the other:

```
public <S extends Shape> void performAction( Action<S> action, S shape ) {
  action.start(shape); 
}
```